# Rails & Shopify: Is there any way to see a full list of Shopify API commands?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I know there is the [Shopify API docs](https://docs.shopify.com/api/product) with all the endpoints e.g `GET/admin/products.json`. But I'm looking for somewhere that I can specifically find all the different commands available from Rails console, e.g.

```
ShopifyAPI::Product.all
ShopifyAPI::Product.first
ShopifyAPI::Product.count
```

etc etc. Where are these all listed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the Ruby library API documentation at http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/shopify_api or you can generate it yourself using `rdoc` or `yard`.